# Dynamically generated XML File Doesn't work on Server but works well on localhost

Tags: php, xml, dom

I generated a XML file in php.  This file generates a xml output perfectly in my localhost and at the same time when I uploaded it to my server it fails.
Error Screen [image: Screen Shot of Error]
Here is the code.

```
<?php  

    include_once("database/db.php");

    $sqlNews    =   "SELECT * FROM news";

    $runSqlNews =   mysql_query($sqlNews);

    while ($rowSqlNews  =   mysql_fetch_array($runSqlNews)) 
        $arrSqlNews[]   =   $rowSqlNews;

        header('Content-type: text/xml');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Cache-control: private');
        header('Expires: -1');
        echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";

        echo '<xml>';

    for($i=0;$i<count($arrSqlNews);$i++) 
    {
        echo "<news>";
            echo "<newsId>".$arrSqlNews[$i][id]."</newsId>";
            echo "<newsAuthor>".$arrSqlNews[$i][news_author]."</newsAuthor>";

            echo "<description>".$arrSqlNews[$i][news_description]."</description>";
            echo "<newsText> <![CDATA[".$arrSqlNews[$i][news_text]. "]]></newsText>";
            echo "<plainNewsDescription>".$arrSqlNews[$i][plain_news_description]."</plainNewsDescription>";
            echo "<plainNewsTitle>".$arrSqlNews[$i][plain_news_title]."</plainNewsTitle>";
            echo "<newsUrl> <![CDATA[". $arrSqlNews[$i][news_url]. "]]></newsUrl>";
            echo "<newsCategory> <![CDATA[". $arrSqlNews[$i][category]. "]]></newsCategory>";
            echo "<image>http://metroplots.com/images/members/".$arrSqlNews[$i][news_image]."</image>";
            echo "<createdOn>".$arrSqlNews[$i][created_on]."</createdOn>";
        echo "</news>";       
    }
        echo '</xml>';
?>
```

New xml File after changes

```
<?php
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

    include_once("database/db.php");

    $dbConn     = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUserName, $dbUserPasswrd, $database);;

    $sqlNews    = "SELECT id, news_author,news_description,
                          news_text, news_url, category, news_image, created_on
                     FROM news";

    $stmt   = $dbConn->prepare($sqlNews);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($id, $newsAuthor, $newsDescription, $newsText, $newsUrl, $Category, $newsImage, $createdOn);


    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Expires: -1');

    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
    echo '<xml>';
    echo "<news>";

    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo "<newsId>".$id."</newsId>";
        echo "<newsAuthor>".$newsAuthor."</newsAuthor>";
        echo "<description>".$newsDescription."</description>";
        echo "<newsText> <![CDATA[".$newsText. "]]></newsText>";            
        echo "<newsUrl> <![CDATA[". $newsUrl. "]]></newsUrl>";
        echo "<newsCategory> <![CDATA[". $Category. "]]></newsCategory>";
        echo "<image>http://metroplots.com/images/members/".$newsImage."</image>";
        echo "<createdOn>".$createdOn."</createdOn>";        
    }

    echo "</news>";       
    echo '</xml>';

    $stmt->close();
    $dbConn->close();
?>
```

Please let me know where I went wrong.  Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Possibly nothing in the `news` table on your remote DB?

Comment: Sorry. This table has 1000's of records on DB.

Comment: What do you see in view page source source.

Comment: Just i tried and It is empty.

Comment: In addition to setting error reporting, you should also display errors, ie `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what exactly goes wrong here.
For debugging, you could add a `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` at the beginning of your script or watch your php error log.

You got a few other problems in your script architecture

- You should no longer use the [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) extension. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.
- The headers should be sent once only. Move them out of your loop to the top
- why do you loop through the result twice? Remove the `for` loop and move its content into the while loop. Within the loop replace the variable `$arrSqlNews` by `$rowSqlNews` and remove the index accessor `[$i]`

Simplified example

```
while( $rowSqlNews = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $mysqliResult ) ) 
{
    echo $rowSqlNews['yourdbCol1'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Let me check it now.

Comment: +1 
This is the day i learned mysqli from you. Thanks for that. I changed all as advised above. I added ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); and no difference on the page. The error remains the same as pasted the screen shot above...

Comment: Could you update your code in your question and add the db.php for a review?

Comment: FYI the headers are not sent in the while loop

Comment: Michel Feldheim ,  Kindly check the newly updated xml script as advised.

Comment: Forgot to mention that this script also works good on my local host. same error on server.

Comment: Looks much better already. What's the content of your db.php include? Check the database credentials this apparently provides

Comment: ah. Yes my database credentials are quietly alright.  Because other admin files include same thing and working good...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling PHP Output Buffering?

In PHP.ini: `output_buffering = Off` or comment out existing setting: `;output_buffering = On`.

Don't forget to restart web server after changing settings.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that your upload tool transfers the file not in binary-safe way. Try to compare file sizes of the copy on your local machine and the remote one.

Comment: NO it is not (.txt) file.  It is (.php) file.

Comment: No doubt. Still, the content of your file is text and can be transferred in ASCII mode